# Almost-flattening a directory structure

Tags: linux, bash, regex, sed

I have a bunch of directories in a structure like this:

```
-Music
  -Artist1
    -Album1
    -Album2
  -Artist2
    -Album1
    -Album3
  -Artist3
    -Album2
    -Album4
```

All the directories will contain unique files.
I would like to reorganise this directory so that the artist directories are removed from the structure:

```
-Music
  -Album1
  -Album2
  -Album3
  -Album4
```

I was thinking of a pattern like `^[^\/]+\/` but I'm terrible at regex, and how to make it actually do something with the mv command.

Comment: Your Album1 of Artist1 will replace Album1 of Artist2 and this would happen to all multiple copies. Is that good for you?

Comment: yep, I expect the new Album1 to contain files that were in any of the old Album1 directories

Answer (score 2):

If you have enough space to temporary make a copy you can simply try this:

```
mkdir Music_new
cp -R Music/*/* Music_new
```

Comment: You don't need a temp copy, just do `mv Music/*/* Music_new && mv Music_new Music`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd Music #Go to Music
mv */* . #Move all Album directories to Music
rmdir *  #Delete all empty directories, that is, Artist ones
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
mv Music/*\/* Music/
```

and then you can remove Album directories.

Comment: You don't need (or want) to escape the `/`.